# Why program is not printing true in second and third line?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

Source Code:

```
public class TestSB{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1="Arnold";
        StringBuffer sb1=new StringBuffer("Arnold");
        StringBuffer sb2=new StringBuffer("Arnold");
        System.out.println(sb1==sb2);
        System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2)); //should be true but printing false
       System.out.println(sb1.equals(s1)); //should be true but printing false
    }
}
```

Above is a Source Code that I have written, the output for line 7 and line 8 both should be true but it is coming false what is the reason behind this?

Output:

```
false
false
false
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: Please also read: [Why can't I upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If you have problems formatting your code, SO has a [markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that can help you out.

Comment: When object of StringBuffer is passed references are compared because StringBuffer does not override equals method of Object class.

Comment: Why "should" it be `true`? Are you under the assumption a `StringBuffer` is the same thing as a `String`? Did you check the docs for `StringBuffer` to see what `equals` it implements? And all the other comments: questions need to stand on their own, and links to images of text are worse only than images of text: post text.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder` do not override `Object#equals`, as you might have expected. You should use `sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())` or `sb1.toString().equals(str)` to compare `SB` as as `String` value.